# Android thread slows down when main activity idle

Tags: android, multithreading, tensorflow-lite

I have a foreground service which gets started from main activity. This service is constantly performing a ML task over audio input with Tensorflow Lite library. When main activity is active everything works fine, but as soon I switch to other app or close the screen inference time goes from 100ms to 400-500ms. The process keeps running in the background on a separate thread but it seems to be slowed down. How can I prevent this from happening?

PS: This happens on my Huawei Mate 10 Pro. It works normal on emulator.

Comment: Looks like the operating system switches the application mode to use the little cores instead of big cores. See https://boinc.berkeley.edu/forum_thread.php?id=12532

Comment: @JaesungChung that indeed seems to be the case